# Word 2007/10 VBA macro to change PageSetup with regard to Page Orientation

Tags: vba, macros

On my position we are likely to format check documents that contain numerous sections due to change of page orientation. There are given restrictions on what should be the dimensions of margins size for Portrait and Landscape orientation. 
What I want to achieve is a macro that would go through the currently opened document, check the orientation of each of the sections and adjust the Margins/Headers/Paper Size (which are different depending on whether the page is portrait or landscape)
Here is what I got so far, but it does only change the Margins to ones from Landscape setup and disregards the header/footer:

```
 If PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
    PageSetup.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
    PageSetup.RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
    PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
    PageSetup.BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
    PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperLetter
    PageSetup.HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.96)
    PageSetup.FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.94)
ElseIf PageSetup.Orientation = wdLandscapeOrientation Then
    PageSetup.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
    PageSetup.RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
    PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
    PageSetup.BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
    PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperLetter
    PageSetup.HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.9)
    PageSetup.FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.9)

End If
Selection.GoToNext wdGoToSection
```

Can you help me out with some examples or working code? The above shows my concept in the most simple way, but tbh I have no experience with creating word macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with code found and adapted from [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/macro-that-affects-margins-but-not-orientation/fd3b2788-2529-4f56-abee-e193eefd8b9f):

```
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    If .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
        .PaperSize = wdPaperLetter
        .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
        .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
        .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
        .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
    Else
        .PaperSize = wdPaperLetter
        .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
        .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
        .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
        .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
    End If
End With
```

Let me know if that code works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, results are the same as in my example:
- whole document gets Landscape margins
- landscape page gets rotated back to portrait
- section break is ignored